# Is there a way to give emacs the KDE look and feel?

Tags: kde, emacs

I'm using emacs for most of my work. I'm switching from gnome desktop to KDE (checking things out) and it bother me that emacs look soo diferent from the rest of the desktop. Is there a way to give emacs the KDE properties?

I was sure there was a qt frontend for emacs but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Emacs can be built with the GTK toolkit and GTK style can be configured to emulate the KDE/Qt look. It won't be a real Qt app, but it will look like one.

Comment: I would have read how it can be configured.

Comment: I don't know the exact details, because I don't use GTK myself, that's why I didn't go into details, but I know GTK supports theming and I read about a GTK-QT theme once. Google surely can help to find out more if someone's interested.

Answer (score 1):

Breeze themes for GTK (and therefore EMACS) are broken by today (2016-04-24).
But there are many color-themes for emacs already.
Try Whiteboard. It really fits in with Breeze.
I didn't look for something to match Breeze-Dark though.

Answer (score -3):

you may use the bundle system of Chakra linux:

http://chakra-linux.org/bundles.html